# Cocoa NSFont 'leading' attribute build error

Tags: cocoa, nsmutabledictionary, nsfont

In an AudioUnit plugin, I'm using NSFont.

```
NSFontManager* fontManager = [NSFontManager sharedFontManager];
NSFont* nativefont = [fontManager fontWithFamily:[NSString stringWithCString: fontFamilyName.c_str() encoding: NSUTF8StringEncoding ] traits:fontTraits weight:5 size:fontSize ];

NSMutableParagraphStyle* style = [[NSMutableParagraphStyle alloc] init];
[style setAlignment : NSTextAlignmentLeft];

NSMutableDictionary* native2 = [[NSMutableDictionary alloc] initWithObjectsAndKeys:
                nativefont, NSFontAttributeName,
                    style, NSParagraphStyleAttributeName,
                    nil];

// .. later
void someFunction(NSMutableDictionary* native2)
{   
    float lineGap = [native2[NSFontAttributeName] leading];
```

Compiler says (about last line): **assigning to 'float' from incompatible type** 'NSCollectionLayoutSpacing * _Nullable'

NOTE: This has only failed recently since switching to Xcode 11.1, on an older version of XCode it built OK. Any help appreciated.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

In your code, the expression `native2[NSFontAttributeName]` is of unknown type, and therefore of type `id`. The compiler will let you send an object of type `id` any message without complaint, but it has no context for determining the type of the message's return value.

You want to get the `leading` property of `NSFont`, but the compiler is just picking any `leading` property selector at random and I'm guessing it has ended up choosing the `leading` property of `NSCollectionLayoutEdgeSpacing` which has a return type of `NSCollectionLayoutSpacing` not `float`.

I suspect that casting the expression `[(NSFont*)(native2[NSFontAttributeName]) leading]` would do the trick, but if I were writing this code I'd simply refer to the original (typed) object, since you already have it:

```
float lineGap = nativefont.leading;
```

Comment: In my case the code I posted is actually scattered around a larger codebase, and `nativefont` was not actually accessible, but casting to `NSFont*` fixed it!